# Как получить содержимое тегов?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Взять содержимое между тегами

```
<div class="label fl_l">текст</div> <div class="labeled fl_l">содержимое</div>
```

я пробовал так:

```
'|<div class="labeled fl_l">(.*)</div>|sei'
```

Нужно изъять только 'содержимое'

Comment: кавычка после `fl_l`

Comment: добавил кавычку, однако это задачу не решает, само выражение не точное.

Comment: А что вы точно даете на вход и что в итоге получаете? Может, у вас там в содержимом или после него еще дивы?

Comment: в содержимом должны быть цифры около 10, но могут встречаться символы. Никаких тегов внутри нет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Текст между дивами с классами **label fl_l** и **labeled fl_l**:

```
preg_match_all('#<div\sclass="label[ed]*\sfl_l">(.*)<\/div>#Uis', $text,$res);
```

Текст только DIV'a с классом **labeled fl_l**

```
preg_match_all('#<div\sclass="labeled\sfl_l">(.*)<\/div>#Uis', $text,$res);
```

Comment: Эээм вы понимаете, что это скорее всего регулярка для большого документа, а нужны не все тексты из всех дивов?)

Comment: Исправил, уже будет выводить только между дивами с классами **label fl_l** или **labeled fl_l** (1-й вариант) и только между **labeled fl_l** (2-й вариант)

Answer (score 1):

Получить все, что находится между тегами

```
$str='<div class="label fl_l">ssome text</div>';
$str2 = preg_match('|<div class="label fl_l">(.*)</div>|sei', $str, $res);
echo  $res[1]; // получим some text
```

Comment: Не получим...

Comment: а вы попробуйте.

Comment: черт тут вырезало теги мне

Comment: Да пожалуйста, вот результат вашего 1-го варианта

    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(0) ""
      [1]=>
      string(0) ""
    }

А вот второго:

    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(41) "some textsome text2"
      [1]=>
      string(41) "some textsome text2"
    }

Comment: да пардон, исправил. теги вырезались у меня.

Comment: И так не будет работать ))

    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(41) "some textsome text2"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "some text2"
    }


вот в вашем случае рабочий вариант

    preg_match_all('|<tag.*>(.*)</tag>|Uis', $text,$res);

Comment: Все будет работать, исправил чисто под вопрос ТС.

Comment: Отвечу вашими словами: "А вы проверьте!" ;)

Answer (score 0):

Мне всегда казалось, что регулярные выражения заключаются в "**/**", а не в "|", а оказывается любой неприсутствующий символ)

Comment: ща будут минусы) заключаются в не-присутствующий символ ;)

    #lol.*# = @lol.*@ = ~lol.*~

Comment: "/" используется в тегах

Comment: Ну не знал я, что-такого. Я литературу читал по регуляркам, там говорилось что /, а сейчас впервые слышу... Но, спасибо.

Comment: там не в | проблема, / тоже не проблема, никто не мешает вам их экранировать `\/`

Comment: в чем же тогда проблема?

Comment: <small>@Sh4dow ты предвидел ^^</small>